# How to return a functions results and set them to the innerHTML of a tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand how recursion works in javascript.  But I'm having problems even getting this function to work properly.

example problem shows calculating power and "potentially" setting the results of the calculation to innerHTML of var my header:

```
var myHeader= document.getElementById("myHeader");
var answer = 0;

answer = power(10, 5);
function power(base, exponent) {
      if(exponent == 0)
       return 0;
      else
       return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }
myHeader.innerHTML = answer;
```

Could you please edit this example code to make it work?
[Example code](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/rncGh)

I just want to use chrome debuggers so I can set a breakpoint and walk through the function one by one to see the order of operations.

I'm taking this function from eloquent javascript by Marijin Haverbeke

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: How do i get the power functions results to be set into var answer?

Comment: `answer` is set to 0..

Comment: `answer = power(10, 5);` ?

Comment: In my tests of `var i = 0; function foo(a, b) { return ++i, foo(a, b); } try {foo();} catch (e) {} i;` I get a maximum stack limit of `17904` (Google Chrome 29 on x64 Win7)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems :

1 You used `var answer = 0`, you didn't assign it to get the result from `power`.

2 Inside your function, you returned 0 if `exponent === 0`, so basically, when exponent = 0, you are returning `base * power(base, 0)` which equals to `base * 0` which in turn equals to 0, so your function will always return 0.

```
var myHeader= document.getElementById("myHeader");
var answer = power(10,5);

function power(base, exponent) {
      if(exponent === 0)
       return 1;
      else
       return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }
myHeader.innerHTML = answer;
```

Comment: This is the best answer but I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I think he is saying you should not recurse when you reach `exponent === 1`, because the next step will make it multiply by `0`

Comment: Ohhh because when you multiply by 0 it will set it to 0 at the end yeah?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Yes, his solution is to say that if `base !== 0` then let the last one return `1` instead of `0`. (I would have always just returned `1` myself because `Math.pow(0, 0); // 1`)

Comment: Marking it coorrect when I can

Comment: changed it to always return 1 to match `Math.pow`.

Answer (score 1):

Your power function is wrong

```
function power(n, p) {
    if(p == 0)
    {
        return 1; // see Math.pow(5, 0) for example
    }
    return power(n, p - 1) * n;
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById('myHeader').innerHTML = power(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myHeader.innerHTML = power(10,5);
```

If you are looking for some ref parameters like in C#: `function(param1, param2, ref param3)`, no, JavaScript has no such parameter.

Comment: Oops. Paul Rad had it in the comment to your question also.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get the power function working, then this is a better solution:

```
document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML = Math.pow(10,5);
```